# Apache Reverse proxy with proxy authentication

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, proxy-authentication

I have the following setup

Box A (192.168.8.180 - running apache reverse proxy)

Box B (192.168.8.100:808 - Proxy server to connect to internet)

Due to internal reasons, The IP of box A is redirected to http://xyz.mydomain.com/. The reverse proxy uses the proxy running in Box B to connect to internet.

**The setup works fine when the proxy does not need any authentication**. But When the proxy at Box B needs authentication, all my request to the reverse proxy fails with the following error.

```
<h1>Unauthorized ...</h1>
<h2>IP Address: 192.168.8.180:1799<br>
MAC Address: <br>
Server Time: 2011-09-21 20:32:16<br>
Auth Result: </h2>
```

Here is my apache configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xyz.mydomain.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyRemote * http://192.168.8.100:808/
    ProxyPass / http://xyz.mydomain.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://xyz.mydomain.com/
    RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic cGFuZGlhbjpwYW5kaWFu"


    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

    ErrorLog "logs/myerror.log"
    CustomLog "logs/myaccess.log" common

</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas?

access log says the following

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2011:20:24:55 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 407 142
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2011:20:24:57 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 407 142
192.168.8.180 - - [21/Sep/2011:20:25:33 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 407 142
192.168.8.227 - - [21/Sep/2011:20:32:07 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 407 142
192.168.8.180 - - [21/Sep/2011:20:32:14 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 407 142
192.168.8.180 - - [21/Sep/2011:20:32:15 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 407 142
192.168.8.227 - - [21/Sep/2011:20:33:58 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 407 142
192.168.8.227 - - [21/Sep/2011:20:35:03 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 407 142
192.168.8.227 - - [21/Sep/2011:20:35:16 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 407 142
192.168.8.227 - - [21/Sep/2011:20:35:24 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 407 142
```

The proxy credentials are correct. verified with browser.

Thanks